# Add Google Maps in JSP

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to use google maps in JSP page, I tried to create it, but it gave me an error of Give API Key.

Comment: read this thread: [Google map in jsp document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364504/google-map-in-jsp-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Maps is a Javascript API. Your issue is not JSP related.

Take a look at the tutorial and let us know if you get stuck. However, it sounds as though you need to apply for an API key, and use that correctly.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html

Comment: The info on how to get an API key is here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps can be used without API Key.A limited amount of data is provided in such a way(might be for testing).However if you want to use it properly then an API key is required for sure.
The Key is generated through Google Api...
Read here
https://developers.google.com/maps/signup